# Can I publish a DJ mix of current chart music online?

Tags: legal

I'm helping to plan an online blog about current music.  The idea is to have DJs create sets of the music being reviewed.

I have heard that there are some avenues where the artists can get their royalties.  I've searched for such sites, but I don't seem to be able to find any.  Can anyone help, or recommend how to go about publishing DJ sets?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an incredible resource for your situation. Although it's centered on Podcasting, it really overlaps with your situation:

[Podcasting Legal Guide](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Podcasting_Legal_Guide)

Here is the section on licenses you will need to be legal. This is very verbose, so I am linking instead of transferring it verbatim:

[Licenses you will need.](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Podcasting_Legal_Guide#Licenses_You_Will_Need.)

And here is the section dealing with *why* you'd need each type of license.

[Using Music](http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Podcasting_Legal_Guide#Using_Music)

It's actually pretty straightforward, but if you haven't done it before, it would behoove you to read up on the details. Comment for clarification if you need more info.